# substring matching in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query

```
select distinct(tad.ASP_NAME)
from TABLE_ASP_DETAILS tad
where tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME = 'asurekam2'
```

where ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME will be equivalent to SureKAM2 and it should return SureKAM2  for the above query.

Similarly

```
select distinct(tad.ASP_NAME)
from TABLE_ASP_DETAILS tad
where tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME = 'ABT_Dallas1_TX'
```

should return ABT from table.

So basically I want contains like functionality in my input string and it should be able to search for something similar in tad.ASP_NAME. ASP Name would be a substring of the input string

ACS_ITALY_CATANIA,ACS_ITALY_BARI,ACS_xxxxx any input  should be able to find ACS value in tad.ASP_NAME

ADNTELECOM_Sayedur_Rahman , ADNTELECOM_Reza_Bin_Mujib, ADNTELECOM_Reza_Bin_Mujib
should be able to find ADNTELECOM value in tad.ASP_NAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
where lower('asurekam2') like '%' || lower(tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME) || '%'
```

Comment: No i want to be able to split ABT_Los Angeles_CA. I need ABT output.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do? You didn't provide test case so I *improvised*. You need lines 6-8.

```
SQL> with table_asp_details(asp_name, assigned_fe_last_name) as
  2    (select 'ACS_ITALY_CATANIA', 'ACS_Dallas1_TX' from dual union all
  3     select 'ACS_ITALY_BARI', 'ACS_Dallas1_TX' from dual
  4    )
  5  -- this is what you need
  6  select distinct regexp_substr(asp_name, '[[:alpha:]]+') result
  7  from table_asp_details tad
  8  where tad.assigned_fe_last_name = 'ACS_Dallas1_TX';

RESULT
-----------------
ACS

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this, but its hard to say with so few details:

```
select distinct(tad.ASP_NAME)
from TABLE_ASP_DETAILS tad
where regexp_like('asurekam2', tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME)
```